# How to find element in a component?

Tags: angular

I am wondering how can I find element inside a component using **Renderer**?

In angular1 I would just go:

```
link = (scope, element, attributes) => {
            var outsideBox = element.find('.outside-box');
}
```

Which returns me a `<div class="outside-box"></div>`

Any pointers are more than welcome!

Comment: Why Renderer, and not `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` (assuming you can add a local template variable to the `div`)?

Comment: @MarkRajcok, I would love to see example of ViewChild usage. Can you provide any link?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use its `selectRootElement` method:

```
import {Component,Renderer} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="outside-box"></div>
      <div (click)="onClick()">Click</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {
  }

  onClick() {
    var outsideBox = this.renderer.selectRootElement('.outside-box');
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9OJ9kr?p=preview

Comment: Funny thing - I was putting the same code as you did in constructor in my component - but it was not working. I had to put it in ngOnChanges -> it seems like constructor is fired before HTML is, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that calling in the constructor is too early because the template is rendered later. `ngOnInit` would be a better place since `ngOnChanges` can be called several times. But you're right the first time it's called, it's before `ngOnInit`...

Comment: actually, i think ngOnChanges seems to be invoked before ngOnInit

Comment: Yes agreed! See my comment above. From angular.io docs: "ngOnInit - after the first ngOnChanges" ;-)

Comment: Does ngOnChange detects the value that has changed?

Comment: Yes, the bound value that has changed. So it can be called several times later...

Comment: `selectRootElement` removes child nodes from the element. I guess it is intended to prepare the element for component init. Certainly not what's required.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't seem to work any more with Render2 in angular 4....

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Plunker - BrowserDomAdapter](http://plnkr.co/edit/9uTJjdsiraXhimewFRPl?p=preview)

```
import {Component,ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
//import { DOM } from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <style>
      .test{
        color:green;
        background:white;
      }
    </style>
    <button (click)="add()" class="btnClass">Add New Element</button>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
 dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
  constructor(el:ElementRef) { 
    this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
    console.log(el);
  }
  add(){

      console.log( this.dom.query(".btnClass"));    
      this.dom.addClass(this.dom.query(".btnClass"),"test");
      console.log(this.el);

  }
}
```

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html

Comment: that angular.io/docs page is 404; do you have an updated link?