# Difference between inputProperty="data.x" and inputProperty="{{data.x}}"

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In my application, I have defined some component, that takes two variables: `start` and `end`. I run it in `ngFor` as follows:

```
 <template ngFor #exampleData [ngForOf]="data" #idx="index">
        <div>
            <example-component start="exampleData.star" end="exampleData.end" *ngIf="exampleData.start" ></example-component>
        </div>
 </template>
```

You can see this in the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0l2MkPVb7KEMEPGBNlKc?p=preview)

As you can see, this code provides `example-component` with a string of either `exampleDate.start` or `exampleData.end`.

It will run as intended when I will add expression  into the component like that:

```
 <template ngFor #exampleData [ngForOf]="data" #idx="index">
        <div>
            <example-component start="{{exampleData.star}}" end="{{exampleData.end}}" *ngIf="exampleData.start" ></example-component>
        </div>
 </template>
```

My question is: why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage property binding for your parameters:

```
<template ngFor #exampleData [ngForOf]="data" #idx="index">
  <div>
    <example-component [start]="exampleData.star"
                       [end]="exampleData.end" *ngIf="exampleData.start" >
    </example-component>
  </div>
</template>
```

This way the content provided for these two parameters are evaluated as expressions.

Without `[...]`, they are considered as strings. In the following, the input values for `start` and `end` are respectively `exampleData.star` and `exampleData.end`:

```
<example-component start="exampleData.star"
                   end="exampleData.end" *ngIf="exampleData.start" >
</example-component>
```

Comment: nice! thanks! any ideas on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055585/renderer-multiple-selectrootelement-issue-with-plnkr-provided ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `start` is an input property, 

`start="exampleData.star"` is equivalent to (a shorthand for) 
 `start="exampleData.star" [start]=" 'exampleData.star' "`.

In other words, it creates HTML attribute `start` with the value `exampleData.star` and it creates DOM property `start` with the value `exampleData.star`.  I don't believe any databinding is created for this.

`start="{{exampleData.star}}"` interpolates `exampleData.star` (meaning that it evaluates `exampleData.star` as an [Angular template expression](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions)), then it converts the result to a string, then it assigns the string result to DOM property `start`. It also sets up a databinding, such that the expression `exampleData.star` is reevaluated each time Angular change detection runs.  If the interpolated string value changes, DOM property `start` is updated.

`[start]="exampleData.star"` is similar to interpolation, with one significant difference:  the template expression `exampleData.star` is not converted to a string.  Whatever value expression `exampleData.star` evaluates to (e.g., it could be an Object or an Array), that value is assigned to DOM property `start`.