# Access whole DOM in Angularl2 RC

Tags: angular

In an **Angular 2** application I need to check whether or not a chrome extension is installed. To do so Google recommends [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) to check for a DOM element added by the extension. I'm implementing the extension as well so it's no problem to add that element when the extension loads.

But I'm struggling with the Angular side. I have a service that handles the  logic with the extension (install etc.), and I would like to implement the check there as well. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to get access to the whole DOM.

There is the injectable class `ElementRef` with the property `nativeElement`, but that only gives me access to the DOM element that belongs to the component. Since the element added by the extension is a direct child of body that does not work here.

Does anyone now how to get access to the whole DOM in an Angular 2 compliant way?

Comment: What about `document.querySelector(...)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer document is available, but I thought it was not a good idea to rely on it since it only exists in the browser. But with your help I found the variable [DOCUMENT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DOCUMENT-let.html) exported by angular. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service) I found a way to inject it to my service. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly solved it by getting @document injected into the constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}
```

and then query for the element

```
this.document.querySelector('#idToCheck');
```

This solution works fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Please check the link provided by tschuege if tempted to used the solution below.

Import renderer:

```
import {Renderer} from '@angular/core';
```

Inject it:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer)
```

Then get the element reference by issuing:

```
renderer.selectRootElement(<elementID>)
```

Comment: Not sure if that is the right way to do it. Have a look a this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055585/renderer-multiple-selectrootelement-issue-with-plnkr-provided).