# how to use selectRootElement angular 2 Renderer method

Tags: angularjs

what is the use of selectRootElement , when I tried to use this Renderer function 
I am getting only root element but it's child not visible on UI .

May I get one example to understand this renderer method ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with using `selectRootElement` if I only want to grab the element? It returns the element without its children and nothing changes in the view! Well, you can still use it of course, but you will be defeating its purpose and misusing it just like people do with `DynamicComponentLoader#loadAsRoot` and subscribing manually to EventEmitter.

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059595/6554634 and here see the question also