# How to focus on a field?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I updated from Angular 2 to Angular 4 and in the docs it's written to use the `Renderer2` instead of `Renderer` which is deprecated.

Now am looking into the Renderer [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render/api.ts), but cannot find a way to invoke the `focus()` method as I used to.

**Old method:**

`this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(element, 'focus', []);`

What is the new aproach?

**EDIT**

What if the element i am focusing onto is obtained via `QuerySelector`?

For instance:

```
let inputField = document.querySelectorAll('.dialog input');
if ( inputField[0] ) {
   inputField[0].focus();
}
```

Since its obtained via `QuerySelector`, the `focus()` method doesn't exist on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element/34573219#34573219

Comment: Please see my updated question. I am using `document.querySelectorAll` method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `invokeElementMethod` is deprecated, and will not find its way back into the new renderer. To set focus to an element, you can simply use this now:

```
element.nativeElement.focus();
```

If you are using `document.querySelectorAll`, you are doing something not the angular way, and you should find another way to do it. If there is no other way to do it, then the same principle applies. The `focus()` method is plain javascript, so you can use it within angular2/typescript. Be sure to do the `querySelectorAll` inside the `ngAfterViewInit` hook of the component though:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   let inputField: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.dialog input')[0];
   inputField && inputField.focus();
}
```

Comment: @Hassan I already updated my answer, because I realised as much. `querySelectorAll` returns an array of `Element`, but you can probably be sure that it's an `HTMLElement`, so you can type hint it to such, so that TypeScript won't complain

Comment: Yeah it now works perfectly fine with your updated answer. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: shouldn't we avoid calling focus directly on nativeElement as we are not using Angular's abstraction layer properly then. Instead should we use Renderer2 APIs?

Comment: @ManuChadha there is no method on the renderer2 to do this :) but perhaps a template ref on the element in the html self and call focus() on that is more angulary

Comment: I agree. I am trying to code the Angular way and also trying to keep abstraction intact but unfortunately the framework isn't as abstract as I thought it would be. Still very new in Angular so I might be wrong

Answer (score 15):

Also you can use **selectRootElement** method of **Renderer2**.

For example:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

this.renderer.selectRootElement('#domElementId').focus()
```

, where **domElementId** is **id='domElementId'** in your html

Comment: Thanks buddy Renderer2 api selectRootElement worked for me


 this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.email.nativeElement).focus();

element.nativeElement.focus(); // not working for me

Comment: Not a recommended approach -- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19554 says, "selectRootElement() is not intended for general use and, as you surmise, and really only useful in bootstrap."

Answer (score 6):

```
template reference variable :#inlineEditControl
<input #inlineEditControl class="form-control form-control-lg"  [placeholder]="label">

 @ViewChild('inlineEditControl') inlineEditControl: ElementRef; // input DOM element

this.inlineEditControl.nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question with the `document.querySelectorAll` method since the field i want to focus should be dynamically selected.

Comment: Again, shouldn't we avoid calling focus directly on nativeElement as we are not using Angular's abstraction layer properly then. Instead should we use Renderer2 APIs?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk), you can set focus using [`FocusMonitor.focusVia`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/api#FocusMonitor) method that is part of [`@angular/cdk/a11y`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y) Accessibility module (A11yModule).

This way you can avoid any DOM manipulation and avoid referencing `nativeElement` altogether.

```js
import { FocusMonitor } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';


export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('elem', {static: false}) elemRef;

  constructor(private focusMonitor: FocusMonitor) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Programmatically set focus. Focus source is 'program'.
    this.focusMonitor.focusVia(this.elemRef, 'program');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At this time, it appears that this task is not achievable without directly modifying the DOM. As others have said, the invokeElementMethod() is deprecated. However, you will find issues with using selectRootElement as well, as this is not its intended purpose and you will end up losing the children inside of your DIV. Here is a link to a SO question that explains selectRootElement in more detail (since the angular docs are atrocious):

[Renderer multiple selectRootElement Issue (with plnkr provided)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055585/renderer-multiple-selectrootelement-issue-with-plnkr-provided)

As for now, it appears the only way to easily achieve your goal is to use a template reference variable, a view child, and the yourViewChild.nativeElement.focus() (though this practice is also not recommended)

There is also a suggested workaround using a FocusService found on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15674

In this issue, Tytskyi mentions that you can implement a FocusService and provide different implementations of focus() based on AppModuleBrowser and AppModuleServer. I'm not sure of the fine details of how that would work but it may be the only way to achieve this without using nativeElement at this time.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this explanation. I know that we should use Renderer2 but I couldn't find an example on how to use Renderer2 to focus on an input. Wondering, why such method isn't available in Renderer2 considering that is seems quite useful. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the correct type of your `inputField` var, you can use any JS query selector.

For instances declaring:
`let inputField: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('.dialog input');`
enables you to call
`inputField.focus();`
that it will work and no TS error will be thrown.