# Is there an Angular2 way to focus on an input field?

Tags: angular, typescript

At the end of a method, I'll be clearing some fields, which is easy enough:

```
this.modelname.fieldname1 = "";
this.modelname.fieldname2 = "";
```

After clearing the fields, I'd like the cursor to appear in `field1`.

Is there an Angular2 way to do this, or do I just use old fashioned Javascript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a template reference variable in the first input, that will give you the ability to run `.focus()` on it.

In your template you can add #fieldName1 to your input tag (i.e. `<input type="text" #fieldName1>`)

in your controller do:

```
@ViewChild('fieldName1')
fieldName1: any;
```

now you can do `this.fieldName1.nativeElement.focus()` in the controller or `fieldName1.focus()` in the template.

Comment: Thanks so much, I would have never found that.

Answer (score 30):

It is not recommended to access dom directly in Angular. Angular provides Renderer (Angular2) and Renderer 2(Angular4) abstractions.

Here is how to do in Angular 2:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input #inp id="myInput" type="text">
      <button (click)="setFocus()">Set Focus</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('inp') inp:ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  setFocus() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.inp.nativeElement, 'focus');
  }
}
```

In Angular4 Renderer is depricated and Renderer2 is added. invokeElementMethod got removed and there is a discussion about it:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13818#issuecomment-297815331

Here is Angular 4 way:

```
 let onElement = this.renderer2.selectRootElement('#myInput');
 onElement.focus();
```

Comment: Plus one for mentioning about the deprecated `invokeElementMethod`

Comment: Two more references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996481/how-to-focus-on-a-field-in-angular and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15674

Comment: The selectRootElement('#myInput') did not work for me (could not locate the element) but I suppose because I had this @ViewChild('myInput') input: ElementRef; at the top.
But @candidJ solution worked for me.
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: and how would it be in a list of inputs? In an email list, but I want to edit what's in position 2, and I want to focus on it

Answer (score 6):

Adding `renderer` way using `@ViewChild` decorator. You can skip using #id attribute as mentioned by @julia above.

It will focus input element once the view is initialized 
Html:

```
<textarea  #tasknote name="tasknote"> </textarea>
```

JS:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('tasknote') input: ElementRef;
         constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){           
          }

       ngAfterViewInit() {
       //using selectRootElement instead of deprecated invokeElementMethod
       this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.input["nativeElement"]).focus();
      }

    }
```

to know more about other functions of `renderer` follow [official](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) docs

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from [How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field) I achieved this by creating an attribute directive that set the focus of the element. This meant that I didn't need to reference elements directly in my component controller and it supports binding.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[appFocusMe]"
})
export class FocusMeDirective {

    @Input("appFocusMe") set focusElement(focus: boolean) {
        if (focus) {
            this.el.nativeElement.focus();
        }
    }

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

And then in the view:

```
<input [appFocusMe]="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way

```
 <input type="text" id="updateField" >
```

js/ts

```
   let element=document.getElementById('updateField');
             element.focus();
```

use in setTimeOut if you get undefinded error

```
 setTimeout(()=>{
                 let element=document.getElementById('updateField');
                 element.focus();                 
             },100)
```