# angular4 wizard first textfield focus on next step

Tags: angular, focus, wizard

I have developed angular4 based wizard, in every step I have form, switching between steps I wanted to have focus on first text-field, I'm able to get focus on first step with html attribute `autofocus` but only when page is loading, when I'm switching between steps not able to get focus.

Tried below examples but unfortunately no success,

[Is there an Angular2 way to focus on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689532/is-there-an-angular2-way-to-focus-on-an-input-field/43691187)

Created a example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Le2AQto4SNm6bFwHhI7A)

Comment: Could you add the content of your research, some code for instance ? That would help others

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the method described in your link above ([Is there an Angular2 way to focus on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689532/is-there-an-angular2-way-to-focus-on-an-input-field/43691187)), but I had to put the call to `focus()` in a `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   (<HTMLInputElement> this.myInputField.nativeElement).focus();
}, 250);
```

Comment: I tried that too, but as I have multiple steps so I'm not preferring this method.