# How to set focus on close button in primeng dialog

Tags: angular, primeng

How to set focus on close button in primeng dialog after it's opened?
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.
HTML:

```
<p-dialog
  [modal]="true"
  [resizable]="true"
  [draggable]="false"
  header="header"
  [(visible)]="dialogVisible"
  (onHide)="closeDialog()"
  (onShow)="openDialog()"
  focusOnShow="false"
>
```

ts:

```
constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>) {}
openDialog() {
    this.element.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Update:
I found solution how to set focus on this element

```
openDialog() {
    const element = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').item(0);
    element.focus();
console.log(document.activeElement)
  }
```

but it doesn't stick. When I check focus inside openDialog it's set, but after that it still sets to another button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Renderer2 to access the element. Something like this:

```
const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#elementId');
```

Then: `element.focus();`

I think you can refer [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) for better understanding.

Comment: This element doesn't have id. It has class and I can find it like this: let element = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-dialog-titlebar-close').item(0) but how to set focus on it?

Comment: I think the following link would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42996588/10342976