# How to programmatically obtain an element reference in Angular without using native API/DOM methods (but Angular API instead)?

Tags: angular, dom, selector

I'm fairly new to Angular, so some of my assumptions will be wrong.

I want to manipulate an element's styling at runtime using `Renderer2.setStyle(elementRef, style, value, flags?)`.
For that, I need an element reference.

The Angular docs always warn against going via a browser's native API to manipulate styling or getting an element reference.

For example, the [docs for `ElementRef.nativeElement`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties) clearly state:

> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed.
>   Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead.
>   Alternatively you can take a look at Renderer2 which provides API that
>   can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not
>   supported.
>
> Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your
>   application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to
>   separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.

Now, the elements I want to style are created on the fly via another component I use.
I don't know, for example, how many of them I will need to touch, so using an annotation-based approach doesn't seem feasible. (The child component will also be rendered after any annotation-based selector is evaluated, I assume?)

Anyhow, I want to select based on CSS class and a custom property, whose value I can compute at runtime (and which will be different from element to element - nothing a `for` loop can't handle, but difficult to express in a text selector?):
`myClass[myProp="val_1..n"]`

**Is there a way to get an element reference using an Angular API**, ie without going through `nativeElement`, like `document.querySelector(...)` or `ElementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(...)`?

I'm basically looking for something like `RendererX.querySelector(componentRef, 'selector')` -  but I take it `Renderer2.selectRootElement(...)` is [*not* what I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059595/2018047)...

**tldr**: how do I go from CSS selector to element reference without going via browser API/DOM methods like `document.querySelector(...)` or calling `nativeElement` myself? Is there an Angular API abstraction?

Comment: Nope, there is no query selector API from Angular.

Comment: We eventually got around the issue by actually using the HTML template better and calling methods from there instead of going via selectors, for example: `<aComponent #elReferenceVariable>
  <ng-template let-data #myTemplate *ngIf="foos$ | async as foos">
    <ng-container *ngIf="foos.length > 0 && myService.getBars(data.baz, data.xyz, foos) as bars">
      <div *ngIf="bars.length > 0" class="pre-box__element--modifier">
        <div 
          class="my-aaa__bbb-ccc" 
          *ngFor="let bar of bars" 
          [ngStyle]="myService.getStylingObj(bar, elReferenceVariable)">`