# angular select element looses data when calling ngrenderer.selectRootElement

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a select element:

```
 <select [id]="item.value.controlName" [(ngModel)]="item.value.outputVarianteValue"
            (focus)="focusControl(item.value.controlName)"                  
       <option *ngFor="let c of item.value.produkte" [ngValue]="c.name">{{c.wert}}</option>
 </select>
```

I rebuild my GUI programmaticaly and want to reset the focus to the element selected before (focusedcontrol)

```
  setTimeout(() => {
              const element = this.ngrenderer.selectRootElement('#' + this.focusedControl);
              console.log('set root focus: ', this.focusedControl, element)
              element.focus();
            }, 0)
```

This works without a problem on normal inputs but not on the selects. After callling `ngrenderer.selectRootElement(#myselect)` my select field is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is here:

[Renderer multiple selectRootElement Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055585/renderer-multiple-selectrootelement-issue/36059595#36059595)

> If you want to preserve content then use the second boolean parameter
>   to true, like this: (using Angular 6+)